Given a subspace $W$ of a vector space $V$, find a subspace $U$ such that $V = U \oplus W$. Why is $U$ not simply $W^{\perp}$?
The title more or less summarizes my question, but I'll elaborate here. I'm still very new to linear algebra, but I'm working through the book Linear Algebra Done Right 4th edition by Sheldon Axler, and this is something that has been bothering me. A lot of the exercise problems in section 2C are problems in the form given in the title, i.e. "given a subspace subject to some constraints, find another subspace such that the two form a direct sum of the full vector space".
The obvious answer occurring to me is simply to take the complement of the given subspace; after all, their intersection will be {0}, and if $W$ is a subspace of $V$, it seems like of course it would be the case that $W + W^{\perp} = V$.
Given this problem appears so many times in the exercise sets, though, I feel like there's no way it can be that simple, but I can't find any reason why it wouldn't be.
Can anyone nudge me toward the (presumably obvious) explanation?

What do you mean by $W^{\perp}$? What kind of "complement" is that?

Your idea is fine if $V$ is an Euclidean space. But what if, for instance, $V=k^n$ where $k$ is some finite field? Or if $V$ is a Hilbert space but $W$ is not closed?

Go find your favorite definition of $W^{\perp}$. I'll bet it depends on an inner product, and not every vector space has an inner product. (Studying vector spaces without relying on an inner product is part of abstract algebra, which might be new to you. In the past you might have wanted the thing you're studying to have as much structure as possible. But now the game is to see how much you can prove while assuming as little as possible.)

Axler really should explain this since I think it's a natural question. The answer is that in an abstract vector space there is no such thing as "the complement"; after all it is defined to be the vectors orthogonal to $V$, but what does "orthogonal" mean in an abstract vector space? You need an inner product or at least a bilinear form to make sense of this condition, like the standard dot product on $\mathbb{R}^n$.
In mathematics we commonly run into vector spaces which are not equipped with inner products, or with bases; this is a big part of why we define and study abstract vector spaces in the first place. My favorite example is the vector space of sequences $a_n$ satisfying the Fibonacci recurrence $a_{n+2} = a_{n+1} + a_n$; this vector space can be used to prove many basic properties of the Fibonacci numbers, such as Binet's formula, and yet there is no inner product or basis in sight.
In an abstract vector space you can define "a complement" (not "the" complement) of a subspace $W$ to be any subspace $U$ such that $W \oplus U = V$, and complements always exist but they are not unique and there is no canonical way to pick one.

This is also why I wish more authors would use a different term like "supplement" to distinguish from (orthogonal) complement.
